# Cannot open r.viewshed on Grass 7

Tags: grass-gis, grass-7.0

I cannot open the r.viewshed tool in Grass 7.0.3. I am using the 64-bit version on Windows 7. The error message is given below:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\grass\grass-7.0.3\gui\wxpython\lmgr
\frame.py", line 776, in OnMenuCmd

GUI(parent=self, giface=self._giface).ParseCommand(cmd)
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\grass\grass-7.0.3\gui\wxpython\gui_
core\forms.py", line 2354, in ParseCommand

raise gcmd.GException(e.value)
core.gcmd
.
GException
:
Unable to fetch interface description for command
'r.viewshed'.
Details: C:\OSGEO4~1\bin\python.exe: can't open file
'r.viewshed': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Do you have problems like this with any other command?

Comment: No, just r.viewshed.

Comment: ok, it is now discussed on the "GRASS user" list, let's hope to figure out the reason and fix it asap. Thanks for the notification.

Comment: I added the issue to https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/ticket/2884

Answer (score 1):

Until the issue is solved, you can install and use function [**`r.viewshed.cva`**](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/addons/r.viewshed.cva.html) from addons